# Material ui Component "Select" does not set the chosen item. Selected item doesn't stay selected, and it renders very small

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, material-components

I got a help last week and I have 50% working of Select Component of Material ui V.5.0 and React 18.0. The list of Select is working properly with map function. The thing is that the selected item doesn't show, it doesn't stay selected. Also the size of the Select component  is not accepting the width format. I've tried, Box and sx={{}},  and none of them worked. Please all helps will be very appreciated.

```js
// Select is down bellow almost at the end. Above the button.

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import KeyboardArrowRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
// import Controls from '../components/Controls';
import Select from '../components/Select';

const initialValues = {
    id: 0,
    fullName: '',
    address: '',
    local: '',
    city: '',
    CEP: '',
    phone: '',
    contact: '',
    email: '',
    numBank: '',
    branch: '',
    account: '',
    balance: '',
    date: '',
    stateId: '',

}


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
    return{
        root: {
           
            display: "flex",
            flexwrap: "wrap",
            
            
        },
        textField: {
            margimLeft: theme.spacing(1),
            margimRight: theme.spacing(1),
            width: "25ch",
        },
        
        field: {
            spacing: 2,
            display: "block",
        }
    }
});

export default function Bancos(){
    const classes = useStyles()
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
    const [fullNameError, setFullNameError] = useState(false);
    const [addressError, setAddressError] = useState(false);
    const [numBank, setNumBank] = useState('');
    const [branch, setBranch] = useState('');
    const [account, setAccount] = useState('');
    const [numBankError, setNumBankError] = useState(false);
    const [branchError, setBranchError] = useState(false);
    const [accountError, setAccountError] = useState(false);
    const [ values, setValues ] = useState(initialValues);

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setValues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        })
    
    }
  

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setFullNameError(false)
    setAddressError(false)

    if(fullName == ''){
        setFullNameError(true)
    }

    if( address == ''){
        setAddressError(true)
    }
    if ( numBank == ''){
        setNumBankError(true)
    }
    if (branch == ''){
        setBranchError(true)
    }
    if (account == ''){
        setAccountError(true)
    }
}


    return(
        <Container>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Typography  variant="h6" color="textSecondary" align="center" gutterBottom
         className="titleBank">
            Cadastro de Bancos
        </Typography>

            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Box mt={3} mb={1}> {/* colocar margim top e bottom com box   */}
                <Grid item xs={6} md={6}>
                <TextField label="Nome do Banco" variant="outlined" color="secondary"
                sx={{width: "430px", ml: 2}} required className={classes.field} name="fullName"
                value={values.fullName}  error={ fullNameError }
                onChange={ handleInputChange }/>
               
                </Grid></Box>
            
                 <Box mt={1}>
                 <Grid item xs={6} md={10} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                 <TextField label="Endereço" variant="outlined" color="secondary"
                 sx={{width: "650px", mr: 1, ml: 2}} required className={classes.field} name="address"
                 value={values.address}
                onChange={handleInputChange} error={addressError}/>
                <TextField label="Bairro"  className={classes.textField} name="local"
                 sx={{width: "350px" }}  value={ values.local }
                 onChange={ handleInputChange }  />
                </Grid></Box>
                <Grid item xs={6} md={10} style={{ display: "flex", margimLeft: 0}}>

                <TextField label="Cidade"  className={classes.field} name="city"
                sx={{width: "320px", mr: 1 }}  value={values.city}
                onChange={ handleInputChange } />

                 <TextField label="CEP"  className={classes.field} name="CEP"
                 sx={{width: "180px", mr: 1}} value={ values.CEP } 
                 onChange={ handleInputChange }/> 
               
                <TextField label="Contato" className={classes.field} name="contact"
                sx={{width: "350px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.contact} 
                onChange={ handleInputChange } />
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={6} md={10} style={{ display: "flex", margimLeft: 0}}>
                <TextField label="Telefone"  className={classes.field} name="phone"
                 sx={{width: "235px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.phone }
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } />
                 <TextField label="Celular"  className={classes.field} name="phone"
                 sx={{width: "235px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.phone }
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } />
                <TextField label="E-mail"  className={classes.field} name="email"
                 sx={{width: "350px", mr: 1 }} value={values.email} 
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } />
              
                 </Grid><br/>
                
                 <Grid item xs={6} md={10} style={{ display: "flex", margimLeft: 0}}>
                 <Box width="150px">
                 <Select  sx={{width: "150px", mr: 1 }} 
                    name="state"
                    label="Estado"
                    value={values.stateId}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    options={Select.choices}
                    fullWidth
                 /> </Box>   
                 <TextField label="Nº do Banco" className={classes.field} required
                 sx={{width: "100px", mr: 1 }} name="numBank" value={values.numBank}
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } error={ numBankError } />   
                 <TextField label="Nº Agência" className={classes.field} name="branch"
                 sx={{width: "150px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.branch } required
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } error={ branchError } />
                <TextField label="Nº Conta Corrente" className={classes.field} name="account"
                 sx={{width: "250px", mr: 1 }}  value={ values.account } required 
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } error={ accountError } />
                 <TextField label="Saldo R$"  className={classes.field} name="balance"
                 sx={{width: "180px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.balance } 
                 disabled />
                 </Grid><br/>
                 <Grid item xs={6} md={8} style={{ display: "flex" }}> 
                <Box mt={4}> {/* colocar margim top e bottom com box   */}
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary"
                 endIcon={<KeyboardArrowRightIcon />} 
                >
                 Salvar
                </Button>
                </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>            
        
            </form>
        </Container>
        
    
    )
}
```

```html
import React from 'react'
import {FormControl, InputLabel, Select as MuiSelect,  MenuItem }  from '@mui/material';

// Selection of a State in Brazil

export default function Select(props) {

  const choices = () => ([
    { id: '1', title: 'Acre'}, 
    { id: '2', title: 'Alagoas'},
    { id: '3', title: 'Amazonas' },
    { id: '4', title: 'Amapá'   }, 
    { id: '5', title: 'Bahia'  }, 
    { id: '6', title: 'Distrito Federal'}, 
    { id: '7', title: 'Espírito Santo' }, 
    { id: '8', title: 'Mato Grosso do Sul'}, 
    { id: '9', title: 'Mato Grosso'}, 
    { id: '10', title: 'Rio de Janeiro'}, 
    { id: '11', title:  'São Paulo' }, 
    { id: '12', title: 'Minas Gerais'}, 
    { id: '13', title: 'Paraná'  }, 

  ]);
  

const { name, label, value, onChange } = props; 


  return (
    <FormControl  variant="outlined">
      <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
      <MuiSelect label={label} name={name} value={value} onChange={onChange}>
        <MenuItem value="">none</MenuItem>
          {
            choices().map(
              item => (<MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.title}</MenuItem>)
            )
          }

        </MuiSelect>

      </FormControl>
    

  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your question, the Select component width you could add fullWidth for FormControl in your Select component and about the selected item doesn't select problem, I revise your data structure and code and provide all below, you can try it, hope this can help you.

```js
// Select is down below almost at the end. Above the button.

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import KeyboardArrowRightIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
// import Controls from '../components/Controls';
import Select from '../components/Select';

const initialValues = { id: '', title: ''} 

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => {
    return{
        root: {
           
            display: "flex",
            flexwrap: "wrap",
            
            
        },
        textField: {
            margimLeft: theme.spacing(1),
            margimRight: theme.spacing(1),
            width: "25ch",
        },
        
        field: {
            spacing: 2,
            display: "block",
        }
    }
});

export default function Bancos(){
    const classes = useStyles()
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
    const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
    const [fullNameError, setFullNameError] = useState(false);
    const [addressError, setAddressError] = useState(false);
    const [numBank, setNumBank] = useState('');
    const [branch, setBranch] = useState('');
    const [account, setAccount] = useState('');
    const [numBankError, setNumBankError] = useState(false);
    const [branchError, setBranchError] = useState(false);
    const [accountError, setAccountError] = useState(false);
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues);

    const handleInputChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setValues({id: e.target.value})
    
    }
  

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setFullNameError(false)
    setAddressError(false)

    if(fullName == ''){
        setFullNameError(true)
    }

    if( address == ''){
        setAddressError(true)
    }
    if ( numBank == ''){
        setNumBankError(true)
    }
    if (branch == ''){
        setBranchError(true)
    }
    if (account == ''){
        setAccountError(true)
    }
}


    return(
        <Container>
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Typography  variant="h6" color="textSecondary" align="center" gutterBottom
         className="titleBank">
            Cadastro de Bancos
        </Typography>

            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                <Box mt={3} mb={1}> {/* colocar margim top e bottom com box   */}
                <Grid item xs={6} md={6}>
                <TextField label="Nome do Banco" variant="outlined" color="secondary"
                sx={{width: "430px", ml: 2}} required className={classes.field} name="fullName"
                value={values.fullName}  error={ fullNameError }
                onChange={ handleInputChange }/>
               
                </Grid></Box>
            
                 <Box mt={1}>
                 <Grid item xs={6} md={10} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                 <TextField label="Endereço" variant="outlined" color="secondary"
                 sx={{width: "650px", mr: 1, ml: 2}} required className={classes.field} name="address"
                 value={values.address}
                onChange={handleInputChange} error={addressError}/>
                <TextField label="Bairro"  className={classes.textField} name="local"
                 sx={{width: "350px" }}  value={ values.local }
                 onChange={ handleInputChange }  />
                </Grid></Box>
                <Grid item xs={6} md={10} style={{ display: "flex", margimLeft: 0}}>

                <TextField label="Cidade"  className={classes.field} name="city"
                sx={{width: "320px", mr: 1 }}  value={values.city}
                onChange={ handleInputChange } />

                 <TextField label="CEP"  className={classes.field} name="CEP"
                 sx={{width: "180px", mr: 1}} value={ values.CEP } 
                 onChange={ handleInputChange }/> 
               
                <TextField label="Contato" className={classes.field} name="contact"
                sx={{width: "350px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.contact} 
                onChange={ handleInputChange } />
                </Grid>

                <Grid item xs={6} md={10} style={{ display: "flex", margimLeft: 0}}>
                <TextField label="Telefone"  className={classes.field} name="phone"
                 sx={{width: "235px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.phone }
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } />
                 <TextField label="Celular"  className={classes.field} name="phone"
                 sx={{width: "235px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.phone }
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } />
                <TextField label="E-mail"  className={classes.field} name="email"
                 sx={{width: "350px", mr: 1 }} value={values.email} 
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } />
              
                 </Grid><br/>
                
                 <Grid item xs={6} md={10} style={{ display: "flex", margimLeft: 0}}>
                 <Box width="150px" sx={{ mr: 1 }}>
                 <Select 
                    name="state"
                    label="Estado"
                    value={values.id}
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    options={Select.choices}
                    fullWidth
                 /> </Box>   
                 <TextField label="Nº do Banco" className={classes.field} required
                 sx={{width: "100px", mr: 1 }} name="numBank" value={values.numBank}
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } error={ numBankError } />   
                 <TextField label="Nº Agência" className={classes.field} name="branch"
                 sx={{width: "150px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.branch } required
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } error={ branchError } />
                <TextField label="Nº Conta Corrente" className={classes.field} name="account"
                 sx={{width: "250px", mr: 1 }}  value={ values.account } required 
                 onChange={ handleInputChange } error={ accountError } />
                 <TextField label="Saldo R$"  className={classes.field} name="balance"
                 sx={{width: "180px", mr: 1 }} value={ values.balance } 
                 disabled />
                 </Grid><br/>
                 <Grid item xs={6} md={8} style={{ display: "flex" }}> 
                <Box mt={4}> {/* colocar margim top e bottom com box   */}
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary"
                 endIcon={<Link />} 
                >
                 Salvar
                </Button>
                </Box>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>            
        
            </form>
        </Container>
        
    
    )
}
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import {FormControl, InputLabel, Select as MuiSelect,  MenuItem }  from '@mui/material';

// Selection of a State in Brazil

export default function Select(props) {

  const choices = () => ([
    { id: '0', title: 'none'}, 
    { id: '1', title: 'Acre'}, 
    { id: '2', title: 'Alagoas'},
    { id: '3', title: 'Amazonas' },
    { id: '4', title: 'Amapá'   }, 
    { id: '5', title: 'Bahia'  }, 
    { id: '6', title: 'Distrito Federal'}, 
    { id: '7', title: 'Espírito Santo' }, 
    { id: '8', title: 'Mato Grosso do Sul'}, 
    { id: '9', title: 'Mato Grosso'}, 
    { id: '10', title: 'Rio de Janeiro'}, 
    { id: '11', title:  'São Paulo' }, 
    { id: '12', title: 'Minas Gerais'}, 
    { id: '13', title: 'Paraná'  }, 

  ]);
  

const { name, label, value, onChange } = props; 


  return (
    <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
      <InputLabel>{label}</InputLabel>
      <MuiSelect label={label} name={name} value={value} onChange={onChange}>
          {
            choices().map(
              item => (<MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>{item.title}</MenuItem>)
            )
          }

        </MuiSelect>

      </FormControl>
    

  )
}
```

When I run the code I changed, the component working well like this:
[image]